# Properties of straddles given different maturities

Tags: options

Lets say one wants to use straddles to "go long vol". Is there any way to give general properties of the different lengths of expiry of such a strategy.  Or general pros and cons of having longer vs shorter.

Or does this depend to much on sentiment?

Comment: If you want to profit from an increase in realized vol (i.e. from bigger than expected stock market movements) buy a short term straddle, if you want to profit from an increase in implied vol (i.e. the option market revises its view of future vol) buy a long term straddle.

Comment: Ofc! Thanks! I have another problem, say that one wants to allocate 10 % to volatility with ones portfolio, how does one go about that? A straddle setup just drains money and sure might give some return every now and then.It is not as simple as allocating to say gold and stocks. Do you have some idea on how to think about that?

Comment: What do you mean with allocate 10% to vol? Remember that if you buy a straddle / strangle for the purposes of capturing vol you need to delta hedge it. This means that you regain a "big" part of the premium paid, what you gain or lose is volatility p/l.

Comment: @ilovevolatility Say I got 100 USD in my portfoilo. a 60/40 is 60 USD in stocks and 40 in bonds. How does one go about creating 10/50/40 i.e 10 % of the capital exposed to vol and then has this kind of "running" between rebalancing

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of liquidating 10 in stocks and buying 10 worth of straddles? Worst case scenario is that when you buy the straddle at whatever implied vol it has, the underlying stock has zero volatility and you lose all your initial premium (which will never happen).

Comment: @ilovevolatility urg, that seems like somthing that would be a large drain on the portfolio. I suppose I need a good way to think about this and some kind of way to allocate parts of the 10 % over each period in order not be make it to "aggresive" but I suppose that is a matter of ones own risk profile and current market view..

Comment: Exactly, you will need to have your own risk limits and views. Maybe I can tell you the maths behind trading/investments, but I certainly can't tell you how to make money out of maths :)

Comment: You should not allocate 10% of your dollars to this trade, but you could allocate so this trade is 10% of your "risk" somehow defined.

Comment: @noob2 thats gonna be to complicated for me..I am looking for a framework which is rather simple.

Comment: ...or simply weigh the straddle like if it were stocks. The straddle weighs its dollar Delta, so having a long straddle in your portfolio is like having a long/short position on the stock that auto-rebalance itself by volatility, moneyness, and time. Of course, this means you have to hedge the "Theta bleed" somehow, e.g. by means of fixed income, but that's the best you can do by using linear instruments only. So just collapse your straddle into your "stocks" portfolio share and rebalance the portfolio like you would normally do. Beware: in this way Vega is not hedged.

Comment: @LisaAnn ah man, do I really need to learn about the greeks?

Comment: @user1, yes, you do. They're just closed formulas. I guess sometimes you have learned stuff like Pythagorean theorem. Then I see no reason why you shouldn't do the same with a simple formula like B&S Delta.

Comment: @LisaAnn I would not go as far as calling BS simple :D I actually understand BS in detail never learned about the greeks tho since I am a math major. The idea of the risk neutral probability measure puzzeles me tho , it seems odd to switch from real world probabiltes to this imo.

Comment: @noob2 I just heard about "back spreads" , what would you say is the difference between doing  a straddle with these and a common straddle? i.e one call and one put back spread

Comment: According to Chris McKhann: "Sell a put, buy 2 further out of the money for less - ie for a credit - that is a basic backspread". He describes it as "an option position that are has a tail risk component but doesn’t have the same time decay, than just buying an OTM put". He is the expert, that's all I know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to profit from an increase in realized vol (i.e. from bigger than expected stock market movements) buy a short term straddle, if you want to profit from an increase in implied vol (i.e. the option market revises its view of future vol) buy a long term straddle.

Cred. to noob2

I would only add that in the first case you are profiting from Gamma, in the second you are profiting from Vega.

Comment: @noob2 is there a general dividing line between short and long term? is 1 month short term?